# spliting a string String in c++

Tags: c++, string, split

I have a function `MakeElementfromString( string k ){}`
i want to split the string and make `struct element{int nr, string s}` with it .
what can i use do do that ? found `strtok` but couldn't use it or maybe i dont know how because is for `char` and some `stringstream` method.. nothing worked for me
 anyone can tell me an idea ? i am not an expert in c++ so explain kind :)
 thank you

Comment: If you are using C++ strings use substr() , rather than strtok.

Comment: How do you want the string to be converted into a struct? What have you tried so far? What worked and what did'nt? And is this a homework question?

Comment: What does the variable "nr" represent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: How to split a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/c-how-to-split-a-string)

Comment: @user745087: I have tried something based on limited information. See if that serves the purpose?

Comment: @Bo: I am not sure if this is a duplicate of that question you indicate. O.P is also asking about stringstream, strtok and related functions. It is a duplicate only in the broadest sense of the term.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use libs use boost::split.

If you can't iterate over your string and put the parts in a vector.

```
string s("test hallo! someothertest");
char separator = ' ';
vector<string> parts;
int token_begin = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i){
  if( s[i] == separator){
     parts.push_back(s.substr(token_begin, i - token_begin ));
     token_begin = i + 1;
  }
}

//get last token if does not end with a separator
if(token_begin != s.size()){
  parts.push_back(s.substr(token_begin, s.size() - token_begin));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, the question has not been edited to say how the OP wants the string to be converted to a struct element. But this is the broad outline of how it might be done.

Assumptions: string s has first two characters that go into int member of struct and the rest of it goes into the string part.

example: s = 01hello
Pseudo-code:

```
string num = s.substr(0, 2);  
string rest = s.substr(3);  

element e;
e.setVal(num, rest);

setVal(string n, string m) {
  str = m;
  istringstream buffer(n);
  buffer >> num;
}
```

where original struct is:

```
struct element {
 int nr;
 string str;
};
```

Comment: @user745087: if it solved your problem, you should upvote and mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for help
made it for

```
struct Telem {
int nrte;
string s;
int dims;
};
```

and i needed to read from file a line and the line to convert into my desire element hope it helps some other people for similar problems

```
Telem TelemDinString( string k )
{
    Telem a;
    Init(a);

    string buf;
    stringstream ss(k);
    vector<string> tokens;
    while ( ss >> buf )
        tokens.push_back(buf);
    int nr;

    stringstream convert( tokens[0] );
    if ( !( convert >> nr ) )
        nr=-1;
    a.nrte = nr;
    a.s = tokens[1];
    a.dims=a.s.length();

return a;
}
```